# Spark port availaibility

Tags: java, apache-spark

My spark code needs to run in client mode because of certain constraints, and the cluster is used by several other applications. I frequently get the following issue:

> ARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.

This happens 16 times, the default value for maxRetries. I cannot change this OR use this with spark.ui.port + maxRetries due to certain business constraints.

**Now, the main issue**:

The application does not exit gracefully after this happens, it just exits, so it gets very difficult to troubleshoot for users since there is no exception in the std out logs, they just stop. The users do not check the spark logs.

Is there any way to check if Spark has successfully binded to a part, and if not, throw an exception? I have searched everywhere but could not find a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a shell script to do this, for example

```
seq=16
count=0
for i in $(seq 4040 $END); 
do
if lsof -Pi :$i -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
    count=`expr $count + 1`
else
    echo "not running"
fi;
done
if count == 0 <spark-submit>
```